# error CS0234: assembly or namespace not found while publishing

Tags: c#, publish, assembly-references

i faced a strange issue today, please see the error below:

**error CS0234: The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace**

Many developers were facing this issue on compile time mode, while compiling the code i was not getting this error but while publishing the code i was getting it.

**What I was doing Before:** 
Adding Reference using solution: i was using project file reference to add reference in my main project.

[image]
**What I did to fix it**
Adding reference using browse: then i pointed direct dll of second project from release folder
[image]

[image]

any one guide me why it was causing this issue? is this still the right approach that i adapted to fix it?

if i use csproj file reference to reference second project in main project do i still need to do some configurations to make that work?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look in your dependencies (under either project or build - I can't remember which now) does the build order look correct?

Comment: what do you mean by build order? kindly put some light on this.

Comment: When you look in the project dependency dialog, it will show you the project build order. (As I say, I can't remember the exact menu right now, but it shouldn't take too long for you to find it.)